# How can I turn off this autoformat feature for PHP in VS Code / Codium

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Codium with the PHP devsense extension. I observe an automatic code formatting feature which I find particularly annoying and want to turn off. I already have turned off nearly every feature of the plugin but it still is there.

When I type

```
private function partialParse() {
```

and then add the final `}`(I turned off automatic bracket closing) then all of a sudden I get an indentation and two additional lines.

```
  private function partialParse()
  {
  }
```

How can I prevent the editor from doing this unwanted automatic formatting?

Disabling the PHP extension completely solves this problem - but it is no option, as I need some features, such as the hints. However, I want to stop the editor from doing **any** automatic formatting, indention, completion etc and show just what I typed.